# changing the value of check-box in JSP using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, checkbox

I'm trying to change the value of my check-box, I want the value of the check-box to equal 'N', when the check-box is not selected. And then the value of the same check-box changed to 'Y' if the check-box is selected. This value will then be saved to my database. At the moment, when I save the check-box, the value is saved as 'ON' when selected and my database field remains blank if the check-box is not selected when I save to my database. Please see code below.

```
<script language="javascript">

    function validate() {
      if (document.getElementById('box1').checked) {
         alert("checked");
         document.getElementById('box1').value == 'Y'

      } else {
         alert("Checkbox not checked!")
         document.getElementById('box1').value == 'N'
      }
    }        

</script>
```

........................

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox3" id="box1" onclick="validate()"> Letter</td>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to save to the database? The problem may lie there.

Comment: Thanks, but its not the database. Its the function, I've managed to change the value to Y when selected, but can't get N to save when its not selecting. Value is only set, if the check-box is ticked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicly, I think this is a problem can be solved by "post form".

When you click the element checkbox, you trigger a function "validate()".
Then it change the value of checkbox.

When this input element is wrapped by a form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/your/url/to/handle/data" name="postForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox3" id="box1" onclick="validate()"> Letter
</form>
```

Your can add a "input submit" element to trigger this form to post:

```
<form method="post" action="/your/url/to/handle/data" name="postForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox3" id="box1" onclick="validate()"> Letter

    <input type="submit" value="submit form" />   <!-- here is the trigger input -->
</form>
```

Then in your handle page,you can receive the key-value in this form.

P.S   the checkbox'key in form element is "name" not "id".
In this demo, you received the data like:
{chkbox3:'Y'}

That's all, hope it can solve your problem. : )

Comment: Thanks for the help @Tyler.z.yang. I do have the check-box wrapped by a form and submit button to trigger the post. But instead of it posting the value 'Y' or 'N', it posts 'ON' or a blank field. I'll try using the name attribute instead of id, that could be it.

Comment: @ConorCaslin I just check it out in search engine, it seems you use the js framework extjs4? In this framework the checkbox's default value is 'on', and that solve the checked problem.  e.g:
{xtype:'checkboxfield',fieldLabel:'CheckBox',name:'checkbox',inputValue:'Y',uncheckedValue:'N'}    :)

Comment: Thanks for the research. Still can't get it to work. I've been trying a few different ways myself. one was to have two check-boxes with the same name, one is hidden, one is not. The hidden checkbox is automatically selected although the user can't see it. If the visible check-box is selected, the hidden one is then unchecked and vice-versa. Visible checkbox is set to value="Y" and the hidden check-box value="N". Can't get it working either though. :(

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong.It was HTML markup checkbox default value is "on".
There is some problem in your javascript code. "document.getElementById('box1') == Y" => "document.getElementById('box1') = Y"  so does the else statement. : )
Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tyler_z_yang/rgjSG/3/

Comment: Got it working. Thanks for all your help. One of the problems was I used two equals (==) instead of (=), but I added another check-box like I said in my last comment, and messed around with it.Ended up doing **<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox3" onclick="alert(validate()" id="box1" value="Y"> Letter
<input type="hidden" name="chkbox3" value="N"> **

Comment: Can you show me all of the code you make? In your html markup,it seems the onclick event "alert(validate()" is a syntax error. If validate have a return value. you can change the onclick like this: "alert(validate())"    : )

Comment: It's grand, it's working now. Thanks for all your help. The alert( validate() ) was just something I added temporarily, so I could see the value of the checkbox when it was selected or not (ticked or not ticked). :)